# Proportions and direct proportion

Tags: calculus

I have a massive sheet of proportion questions and I just can't get my head around any of it

The distance $D$ traveled by a particle is directly proportional to the square of the time $t$ taken. Suppose $t=40$, $D=30$.

Find the formula for $D$ in terms of $t$.

Calculate the value of $D$ when $t=64$.

Calculate the value of $t$ when $D=12$ in $3$ significant figures.

Comment: $D=kt^2$ where $30=k\times 40^2$.  Can you find $k$?

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

$D=kt^2$
Given $(D,t)=(30,40)$
$k=0.01875$

Now for second question: $D=0.01875*(64)^2$
For third question; $t=\sqrt{\frac{12}{0.01875}}$